# Impress text autoscaling broken?

Tags: libreoffice

Usually the textsize adapts to fit the slide, but on one slide it doesn't work. There aren't any spaces at the end and if I disable the bullets the text scales fine. Is this a bug or intended and is there a workaround? I use version 3.4.
Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This almost definitely a bug, though the screenshot being so small, and you not being in normal view makes it hard to tell what you are seeing there.

I would suggest reporting a bug.